# What is the equivallent of SELECT TOP N in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume the following schema:

```
{
  "document" : {
    "properties" : {
      "DocumentTitle" : {"type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed", "analyzer":"keyword", "store":true },
      "ReceptionDate" : {"type":"date", "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "store":true }
    }
  }
}
```

What i am trying to do is to fetch TOP 5 documents by reception date (thus 5 most recent documents) however i want them to be sorted by another field (DocumentTitle) so simply sorting by date and limiting to 5 results is not enough.

Is this possible through 1 query or multiple queries are required ?

**UPDATE (as per Sidharthan request):**

I am coming from RDMS world where this is a very common issue, solved using TOP or group by statements. Thus, I expected this would be a simple yes/no response whether ElasticSearch supports such functionality (TOP) or not.

I created the demo data below to help you better understand my issue:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/custom/

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/_mapping
POST data:
{
    "document" : {
         "properties":{
             "DocumentTitle": { "type": "string", "store": true },
             "ReceptionDate": { "type": "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ", "store": true }
        }
    }
}

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"A.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2001-01-01T00:00+0000"
}


POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"B.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2002-01-01T00:00+0000"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"C.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2003-01-01T00:00+0000"
}


POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"D.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2004-01-01T00:00+0000"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"E.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2005-01-01T00:00+0000"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"F.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2006-01-01T00:00+0000"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/custom/document/
POST data:
{
    "DocumentTitle":"G.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2006-01-01T00:00+0000"
}
```

The result of Sidharthan's proposal is (i used URI search for shorter size in the post):

```
GET http://localhost:9200/custom/document/_search?q=DocumentTitle:*&sort=ReceptionDate:desc,DocumentTitle:asc&fields=ReceptionDate,DocumentTitle&size=5&pretty=true
```

-- RESPONSE --

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 7,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "custom",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "v6gLeB9kSOCc5OgoTLT6BA",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
    "DocumentTitle":"F.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2006-01-01T00:00+0000"
},
      "sort" : [ 1136073600000, "f.pdf" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "custom",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "DJGivLtOQsW6DAGA5wgQzA",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
    "DocumentTitle":"G.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2006-01-01T00:00+0000"
},
      "sort" : [ 1136073600000, "g.pdf" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "custom",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "ic3v37xGQtydrjb-RaJl4g",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
    "DocumentTitle":"E.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2005-01-01T00:00+0000"
},
      "sort" : [ 1104537600000, "e.pdf" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "custom",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "kCcgoiodQKuxsD9n6ZGifw",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
    "DocumentTitle":"D.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2004-01-01T00:00+0000"
},
      "sort" : [ 1072915200000, "d.pdf" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "custom",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "jUYP0d3pSmSjlMqw3TsS1Q",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
    "DocumentTitle":"C.PDF",
    "ReceptionDate":"2003-01-01T00:00+0000"
},
      "sort" : [ 1041379200000, "c.pdf" ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

This is perfectly **correct result set in terms of data contained**. **BUT** it is in the **wrong order**.

I need these items **ordered by DocumentTitle ONLY (C, D, E, F, G)**.

Unless ES supports some kind of TOP, i think the only solution is to fetch the resultset ordered by ReceptionDate and then do manually the ordering in the client as kielni suggested.

Comment: Can you do the sort in whatever is receiving the results?

Comment: Well yes, it is possible to sort on the client side however i am trying to find out whether it's possible to receive the results pre-sorted from the ES as well.

Comment: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/6124 and
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256 indicate this is possible in 1.3 (syntax is a bit dense so cannot give an example)

Comment: Hi Okigan, i m not more working on that project for which i started this thread so i cannot test right now. If i find some time at home i ll check your proposal as it seems it does the trick.

If anyone else confirms its working pls comment here and i'll be happy to update & accept that as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems this is not possible with ES currently.

I ll proceed with fetching the result set and apply order in the client.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort for both fields. First sort by `ReceptionDate` and then sort by `DocumentTitle`. 
Try

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "ReceptionDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "DocumentTitle": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  },
  "size": 5
}
```

Comment: Hi, this was my 1st thought. It's wrong though..

I want top 5 by date, but i want them sorted by title..

With your proposal i get top 5 by date however the sort is primarily done by date and THEN by title.

Comment: This would bring the top 5 by title. This is not what i want either :) ..

In previous case, the result set would be correct with wrong order (sorted first by date then by title when i want only by title). But now it will be completely wrong result set...

Comment: jus try with my edited answer..(can you pls provide your data about your prob and some example data to wrk with..!)

Comment: I edited my original post & added the info you requested. Thnx!

Comment: i did created new index and tried.. Sry i couldnt succeed.. thanks a lot for providing a demo data..

Comment: I don't think we can get top n globally by sorting, because it gets top n in each shard, then find top n within these data, so the final top n may be not global top n, here is the detailed explanation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts